# How do I configure openAM admin language

Tags: openam

is it possible to configure the language of openAM 11.0 administration pages (beside setting the default language of my browser/operating system)?

Being new to openAM and trying to learn from tutorials and manuals is confusing when the admin UI is translated into German ;-)

Thanks,
Rainer.

Answer (score 1):

The admin console is always being displayed in the same language as the authentication originally was performed with, so you should be able to see everything in english on the admin console if you authenticate at /openam/console?locale=en

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Clearing all cookies and calling /openam/console?locale=en redirects me to an english login page, however, after authentication, the final frontpage (openam/task/Home) is German again. appending ?locale=en does not help

Comment: Very odd, works fine on my end. :( Looking at the code suggests that the locale is grabbed from the "Locale" session property. You could enable message level debug logging, and then login and logout. After that the Session debug file should show all the session properties, and there you should see if "Locale" property has the correct value.

Comment: Mhmm, OK, I did not try to check the logs, but what I did: setting my Windows and Chrome browser to English, redeployed the application including clearing the old openAM config dir, ---> still German. Tried to find the translations in webapps by grep, without success. Is it possible that there are special war archives for particular languages? I did not download my version on my own, so I do not know the download process.

Comment: I'm wondering if it will help to delete the account and create a new one while the PC language is set to English.

Comment: I have the same problem in France. Tried creating a new account on an English PC, removed everyting from Tomcat, removed the 2 folders from the root directory, but incredibly the UI is still in French!

Comment: Tried deleting both accounts, removed the stuff in Tomcat, removed the 2 folders in the root directory. Then switched to private browsing in Firefox. Then created an account on the English PC. Downloaded the stuff and started over. Still in French!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default language by specifying the following JVM arguments before starting your app server :

```
-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
```

There is also one reference of the installation language that you might need to change, in the internal OpenDS used by OpenAM. I could not find any user interface to change the setting, so you must change it through LDAP.

- Using any LDAP client, connect to the local LDAP on port `50389` using `cn=Directory Manager` and the password of the `amAdmin` account
- open the following dn :

  ```
  ou=server-default,ou=com-sun-identity-servers,ou=default,ou=GlobalConfig,ou=1.0,ou=iPlanetAMPlatformService,ou=services,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org
  ```
- change the value of one of the `sunKeyValue` attributes :

  ```
  serverconfig=com.iplanet.am.locale=en_US
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked for me:

-Change in your web browser preferences the order of prefered languages, put the prefered language first (in firefox and Iexplorer there is a option with a list).

-Launch the server with the -Duser.language=en java option. (  JAVA_OPTS in setenvh.sh in my local Tomcat setup)

I had to change both options. Not only one.

See also:
https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/install-guide/chap-custom-ui#lookup-for-ui-files